# Is synchronous code always bad choice over asynchronous code while writing high-performance service in Node.js?

Tags: javascript

Are there any example situations which can clarify about the selection of synchronous vs asynchronous selection of coding.

Answer (score 3):

> Is synchronous code always bad choice over asynchronous code while writing high-performance service in Node.js?

Yes, see [this guide in the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) for details. Here are a couple of relevant quotes from it:

> Here's a good rule of thumb for keeping your Node server speedy: *Node is fast when the work associated with each client at any given time is "small".*
>
> This applies to callbacks on the Event Loop and tasks on the Worker Pool.

*(their emphasis)*

And:

> **Why should I avoid blocking the Event Loop and the Worker Pool?**
>
> Node uses a small number of threads to handle many clients. In Node there are two types of threads: one Event Loop (aka the main loop, main thread, event thread, etc.), and a pool of k Workers in a Worker Pool (aka the threadpool).
>
> If a thread is taking a long time to execute a callback (Event Loop) or a task (Worker), we call it "blocked". While a thread is blocked working on behalf of one client, it cannot handle requests from any other clients. This provides two motivations for blocking neither the Event Loop nor the Worker Pool:
>
> 1. Performance: If you regularly perform heavyweight activity on either type of thread, the throughput (requests/second) of your server will suffer.
> 2. Security: If it is possible that for certain input one of your threads might block, a malicious client could submit this "evil input", make your threads block, and keep them from working on other clients. This would be a Denial of Service attack.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check this discussion -

https://www.quora.com/Is-synchronous-code-always-bad-choice-over-asynchronous-code-while-writing-high-performance-service-in-Node-js